# How to reverse an accepted Facebook Friend request from a hacked account

Tags: facebook, hacked

A Facebook friend's account was hacked and the hacker sent out Friend requests to her friend list.  I accepted the bogus request.  Now I don't know how to block the person.  My Activity Log does not show the hacked friend request or that I accepted it.  On my Friend List, it shows that I have 50 friends, but when I count my friend list there are only 49 friends.  It shows 1 recently added friend, but when I click on the Recently Added link, it is blank.  It appears whoever sent the request is not showing up, but is still there.  How do I block this person now?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the user's account in question is disabled.
The friend count discrepancy can be just caching.

To be positive you can just let your friend head to facebook.com/hacked and let the process take of any inconsistencies that might have happened.

If the request isn't in your notifications or email, then you're going to have to remember the account by memory or your browser history.